# Ajax sorting server-side, is iSortCol_0 considering hiddend columns?

Tags: javascript, ajax, datatables

I don't know if it's a bug, but I have a datatable+ajax with the following options:

```
     "bServerSide": true,
     "sAjaxSource": url,
     "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
        jQuery.ajax({
           "dataType": 'json',
           "type": "POST",
           "url": sSource,
           "data": aoData,
           "success": fnCallback
        });
     },
     "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
     "aoColumns": [
                    { "sName": "Id", "sType": 'numeric', "bVisible": false },
                    { "sName": "PostingDate", "sType": 'Date' },
                    { "sName": "Userid", "sType": 'string', "bVisible": false },
                    { "sName": "DisplayName" },
                    { "sName": "Description" },
                    { "sName": "MainTag" },
                    { "sName": "Tags" },
                    { "sName": "HowMuch" }
                ]
```

I have a form where users can add rows and when they submit it I add data to the database with an ajax call and then call:
    jQuery('#mydatatable').dataTable().fnReloadAjax();

When a user click to sort the table by column "MainTag" my server-side ajax receives:

```
iSortCol_0 4
iSortingCols 1
```

And all bSortable_# are there, correctly from 0 to 7 (I have 8 columns as shown above.

Now my problem is iSortCol_0 is misleading, since the columns where hidden, if I don't have a mean to know which columns are hidden on the server I misinterpret iSortCol_0=4 sorting by the wrong column.

I can implement a workaround, sending the information of which columns are displayed or hidden externally to datatables but I have the feeling either I am doing something wrong or I have missed to find the answer to my problem in the documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that there is an automatic way to know that, what i'd do is send an extra parameter to the server using `fnServerParams()` (as detailed in [this](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/custom_vars.html) example) to inform the server about what columns are hidden

```
    "fnServerParams": function ( aoData ) {
        aoData.push( { "name": "more_data", "value": "my_value" } );
    }
```

Comment: Thanks/Grazie. Looks like a reasonably standard solution!